# Inset spacing different on other computer

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, cs6, mac

My business partner and I are working on the same document in InDesign. I made a master that is good to go, but every time he starts to change stuff in the document the whole design becomes different because (apparently) if he wants the same space above the text he has to change the inset spacing to top: 4.

I checked the main settings and if there is anything different between those but I can't find anything. We're both running CS6 on a mac, use the same font and everything, but somewhere my InDesign adds 4 at the top of the text boxes or his InDesign deducts 4 at the top of text boxes.

How can we make this the same?  Is there something we need to check?

Answer (score 1):

This *could* be due to default paragraph styles.

If you use the [Basic Paragraph] style (or he does) and you alter it... any *other* copy of InDesign will **not** have those alterations, but *will* have that [Basic Paragraph] style. InDesign will assume you want *your* settings for that style and will merge some settings and discard others.

In Short, if you are using Paragraph (or Character) styles, **never** use the [Basic] options and **always** create a custom names style so that it transports with the document. The reality is you should really *never* alter the [Basic Paragraph] style unless you are 100% certain no one else, ever, will use the InDesign file. But even then, upgrading versions can cause some issues for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Either one or both InDesign copies could have a global setting made that will affect your formatting. Global settings are those that are made before opening any documents and will affect any new document you create. Check the global Character and Paragraph palette settings and/or the *Basic Paragraph* settings on each machine, with no documents open. There could be a global value that affects your inset spacing. Ultimately, reset the preferences on both machines by holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>OPTION</kbd>+<kbd>COMMAND</kbd>+<kbd>CONTROL</kbd> while restarting InDesign.